# How to Summarize and Calculate Proportions in Power BI using DAX/M CODE for WIDE/Horizontal format data

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, powerbi-desktop, m

I hope you're all doing well. I'm currently working on a Power BI project and I'm facing a challenge with transforming and summarizing the data in wide/horizontal format, I have a dataset structured as follows:

| critical_level | id_trans | agent | period | type_a | type_b | type_c |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a1 | mark | may | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 1 | a2 | mark | may | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 0.5 | a3 | mark | may | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | a4 | sam | may | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 0 | a5 | sam | may | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | a6 | sam | may | 1 | 0 | 0 |

please keep in mind that the cols type_a, type_b and type_c are calculated columns created from the raw data.

This is how they are calculated, I have the same three cols in my raw source data but instead of a number I have a categorical value with the mark "Present" or "Not Present" so I transform them into 0 and 1 (1 if present).

Here's a breakdown of the steps I'm trying to achieve:

1 Filter the dataset based on "critical_level" greater than zero.

2 Sum the "type_a," "type_b," and "type_c" columns for each group (agent and period).

3 Create a "subtotal" column as the count of each observation per group.

4 Calculate the proportions of "type_a," "type_b," and "type_c" over the "subtotal."

My goal is to transform this dataset into a summary table grouped by "agent" and "period." Here's the desired output:

| agent | period | type_a | type_b | type_c | subtotal |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| mark | may | 0.67 | 0.33 | 0.67 | 3 |
| sam | may | 1.00 | 0.00 | 0.50 | 2 |

Comment: hi, it seems "subtotal" column is not the sum of the three types, mark-may should be 5 and sam-may should be 3. Also if it is the sum of three types, the sum of proportions of three types should be equal to 1. Is "subtotal" refer to count of rows or something else? Please kindly check.

Comment: Could you please show your source data before adding the calculated columns, and explain how you calculated them? It might be easier to first transform the data, and then do the calculations.

Comment: Hello Guys it will be awesome if it was a DAX solution, or Power Query , I will edit my question to show how to calculate subtotal thanks

Comment: Sia thank you i made a mistake I have corrected my question thank you for pointing that out

Comment: RADO thanks for your point I have edited my question to account for that thanks a lot

Comment: I have provided an answer for the first question. If you want an answer to the second question, please check the results match the starting data and ask a new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're best doing this type of reshaping in Power Query.

Start:

[image]

Filter out zero:

[image]

Create a group by as follows:

[image]

[image]

In the formula bar for the last step, change it to the following:

```
= Table.Group(#"Filtered Rows", {"agent ", "period "}, {{"type_a", each List.Sum([#"type_a "])/Table.RowCount(_), type nullable number}, {"type_b", each List.Sum([#"type_b "])/Table.RowCount(_), type nullable number}, {"type_c", each List.Sum([type_c])/Table.RowCount(_), type nullable number}, {"subtotal", each Table.RowCount(_), Int64.Type}})
```

[image]

Full code:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"critical_level ", type number}, {"id_trans ", type text}, {"agent ", type text}, {"period ", type text}, {"type_a ", Int64.Type}, {"type_b ", Int64.Type}, {"type_c", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Changed Type", each ([#"critical_level "] <> 0)),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Filtered Rows", {"agent ", "period "}, {{"type_a", each List.Sum([#"type_a "])/Table.RowCount(_), type nullable number}, {"type_b", each List.Sum([#"type_b "])/Table.RowCount(_), type nullable number}, {"type_c", each List.Sum([type_c])/Table.RowCount(_), type nullable number}, {"subtotal", each Table.RowCount(_), Int64.Type}})
in
    #"Grouped Rows"
```

Comment: thanks Davide Bacci I will be making a new question regarding the change from wide to long format

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76890520/using-dax-in-powerbi-to-change-data-format-from-wide-to-long