# Using DAX in PowerBi to change data format from wide to long

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

I hope you're all doing well. I'm currently working on a Power BI project and I'm facing a challenge with transforming and summarizing the data in wide/horizontal format, I have a dataset structured as follows:

| critical_level | id_trans | agent | period | type_a | type_b | type_c |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a1 | mark | may | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 1 | a2 | mark | may | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 0.5 | a3 | mark | may | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | a4 | sam | may | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 0 | a5 | sam | may | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | a6 | sam | may | 1 | 0 | 0 |

please keep in mind that the cols type_a, type_b and type_c are calculated columns created from the raw data.

This is how they are calculated, I have the same three cols in my raw source data but instead of a number I have a categorical value with the mark "Present" or "Not Present" so I transform them into 0 and 1 (1 if present).

My goal is to explode/pivot the data into long format as follows

| critical_level | id_trans | agent | period | type_col |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a1 | mark | may | type_c |
| 1 | a2 | mark | may | type_a |
| 1 | a2 | mark | may | type_b |
| 0.5 | a3 | mark | may | type_a |
| 1 | a4 | sam | may | type_a |
| 1 | a4 | sam | may | type_c |
| 1 | a5 | sam | may | type_a |
| 1 | a5 | sam | may | type_b |
| 1 | a6 | sam | may | type_a |

please notice that I have already filtered out critical value equal to zero.

I will appreaciet a DAX solution but all porposed solutions are more than welcome" thanks a lot guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the DAX solution.

[image]

```
Table 2 = 
UNION(
    SELECTCOLUMNS(FILTER('Table','Table'[type_a] <> 0), "critical_level", 'Table'[critical_level], "id_trans", 'Table'[id_trans], "agent", 'Table'[agent], "period", 'Table'[period], "type_col", "type a"),
    SELECTCOLUMNS(FILTER('Table','Table'[type_b] <> 0), "critical_level", 'Table'[critical_level], "id_trans", 'Table'[id_trans], "agent", 'Table'[agent], "period", 'Table'[period], "type_col", "type b"),
    SELECTCOLUMNS(FILTER('Table','Table'[type_c] <> 0), "critical_level", 'Table'[critical_level], "id_trans", 'Table'[id_trans], "agent", 'Table'[agent], "period", 'Table'[period], "type_col", "type c")
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Bring the data into powerquery and

click select leftmost 4 columns

right click .. unpivot other columns..

click arrow atop value column and remove check mark next to the [x]0

click select value column, right click and remove

Comment: is there a way to do it in DAX? as a table?

Comment: I'm sure there is. Let's see if someone posts one

Answer (score 1):

Super easy. right-click your table in PowerBI, then select Edit Query from the menu. Then in the query editor window, select the critical_level, id_trans, agent, and period columns, then in the Transform tab, click Unpivot Other Columns. Apply that, and you're done.

Comment: You forgot the filter part